# NavigationDrawer ResourcesNotFound

Tags: android, svg, vector, navigation-drawer

I've made some custom icons in inkscape, saved as svg and transform the svg to the vector drawable. The drawable i saved under the `drawable-v21` folder. After this i add the new vector to the navigation drawer menu. After this i open the layout which include the menu and i see my custom icon, everything fine.

But if i start the app i get a `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` and if i looking through the exception i see at the end a `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004d`.

I have no idea why, because i see the icon in the layout preview.

Any ideas?

What i have done: gradle sync, invalidate and restart android studio.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: what's api version you run your app on?

Comment: The minSdkVersion is 15 and targetSdkVersion is 23.

Comment: I am asking what is version you **run** on when error triggers.

Comment: It's running on version 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's running on version 19

Since you are putting your drawable in `drawable-v21` folder it means it is intended for API 21 and up, as as you are running on API 19 there's no drawable available, hence the Exception. So you must either provide alternative drawable for other APIs or do not access this drawable when app is running on pre 21 API

mandatory read - docs on [providing resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: thanks. But in other words i can not use this in api level below 21?

Comment: No. You explicitly said that this is for 21 (or up).

Answer (score 1):

For those they running in the same problem, you must search for a file calling `drawables.xml` in this file android define the fallback/alternative image. It look's like this:

`<item name="custom_image_xml" type="drawable">@drawable/custom_image</item>`

and in the navigationdrawer menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_overview"
    android:icon="@drawable/custom_image_xml"
    android:title="@string/action.overview" />
```

Note: That's "_xml" suffix is only used to explain and illustrate the mapping in the `drawables.xml`